# Rails form_for with route namespace and as attribute

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, routes, helper

I'm using form_for helper with Rails 5 using route namespace feature and as alias for model name.

My routes:

```
      edit_customer_profile GET    /customer/profile/edit(.:format)                                           customer/profiles#edit
           customer_profile PATCH  /customer/profile(.:format)                                                customer/profiles#update
                            PUT    /customer/profile(.:format)                                                customer/profiles#update
```

My view:

```
... omit verbosity ...
<%= form_for [:customer, current_user], as: :profile do |f| %>
... omit verbosity ...
```

My error:

```
undefined method `customer_user_path' for #<#<Class:0x007f0f8d0ddce0>:0x00558c965b4a78>
```

With docs in the hand, the form helper must be use `customer_profile_path` not `customer_user_path`.

Comment: `<%= form_for [:customer, (current_user, as: :profile)] do |f| %>` not sure if this works.

Comment: No, don't works

Answer (score 0):

use `form_with[:customer, current_user], as: :profile do`

Comment: No, return a error `wrong number of arguments (given 1, expected 0)`.